# Custom Control Display Issue

Tags: vb.net, class

I have created this class in visual Basic it works fine but there is a slight [design  issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz45y.jpg). As you can see there is this small bumb, how can I fix this? And also, how can I fix the spacing between the content Box and the selection menu.

```
Public Class VerticallTabControll
    Inherits TabControl

    Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        DoubleBuffered = True
        SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed
        ItemSize = New Size(30, 170)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub CreateHandle()
        MyBase.CreateHandle()
        Alignment = TabAlignment.Left
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim selected As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204))
        Dim notSelected As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(63, 63, 70))



        Dim B As New Bitmap(Width, Height)
        Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(B)




        G.Clear(Color.FromArgb(63, 63, 70))

        For i = 0 To TabCount - 1
            Dim TabRectangle As Rectangle = GetTabRect(i)



            If i = SelectedIndex Then
                '// if tab is selected
                G.FillRectangle(selected, TabRectangle)
            Else
                '// tab is not selected
                G.FillRectangle(notSelected, TabRectangle)
            End If

            'Line Test
            'Dim start As New Point(10, 31 * (i + 1))
            'Dim ende As New Point(160, 31 * (i + 1))
            'G.DrawLine(Pens.White, start, ende)


            G.DrawString(TabPages(i).Text, Font, Brushes.White, TabRectangle, New StringFormat With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center})

        Next

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(B.Clone, 0, 0)
        G.Dispose() : B.Dispose() : selected.Dispose() : notSelected.Dispose()

        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        e.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "bumb"?   What exactly do you not like about the display?

Comment: Well the content and the menu differ in hight.

Comment: Add me to the list of users that can't see what problem you are asking us to solve.  Don't call `e.Dispose()` and use TextRenderer.DrawText instead of DrawString.

Comment: @LarsTech well I tried to use textrender.drawtext but it didn't worked on the online dokumentation is pointed out that you can't use it in forms so there is that

Comment: Where on earth did you read that?  Didn't work doesn't help us help you.  Maybe we need a bigger image to see what the problem is, because right now, no one knows what the problem is.

Comment: You cropped the image so closely that we cannot tell the size of anything but that blue thing.  There is nothing else to compare the size, location or alignment.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/Ot65I) here is a better image. The white box is slighly higher than the blue one I want to fix this

Comment: I still no idea what you are talking about. The only "white boxes" are 2 ListBoxes and a ComboBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try overriding the DisplayRectangle property to adjust the interior space accordingly:

```
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DisplayRectangle As Rectangle
  Get
    Return New Rectangle(MyBase.DisplayRectangle.Left,
                         MyBase.DisplayRectangle.Top - 2,
                         MyBase.DisplayRectangle.Width + 2,
                         MyBase.DisplayRectangle.Height + 4)
  End Get
End Property
```